# Kill apache processes when memory usage reaches 90%

Tags: apache, ubuntu, kill-process, rackspace

My situation is following:
We run Magento Professional on a 15Gb ram instance, rackspace.

When running htop, we could see that 'apache2 -k start' keeps spawning more child processes, someone them eats ~900Mb of memory.

When memory is almost used up, all sites time out or become very slow.
When memory is all used up, it seems that some of these processes got killed to free memory.

Then the same procedures happen.

My question is, could we setup ubuntu / apache to kill off child processes and free memory when memory usage reaches 85-90% ?

Comment: Is it irrelevant that all requests will be instantly terminated and clients will get a "server unexpected closed the connection" message? Have you looked at tweaking the `ServerLimit` in Apache config?

Comment: Better to try a restart to apache2 instead simply killing them all.. Put a script for it and run as cron frequently like 5 minutes to check the mem usage.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting this script in your server as cron for every 2 or 5 minutes

```
#!/bin/sh
TOTAL=`cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal: | awk '{print $2}'`
USEDMEM=`cat /proc/meminfo | grep Active: | awk '{print $2}'`
LOG=/tmp/test.log
echo > $LOG
if [ "$USEDMEM" -gt 0 ]
 then
     USEDMEMPER=$[$USEDMEM * 100 / $TOTAL ]
     echo "Current used memory = $USEDMEMPER %"
     if [ "$USEDMEMPER" -gt 90 ]; then
         killall -9 apache2
         service apache2 restart
         echo "apache process killed " >> $LOG
     fi
fi
cat $LOG
```

This will kill your apache processes when the used memory reaches 90% and restarts the apache2. If you don't want to set as cron, Simply run this script at any time you wish to regulate the memory consumed by apache.

Hopes this will help your requirements.

Comment: Good way of calculating memory differences